# Reading and executing a simple predefined programming language in Java

Tags: java

We have to read and execute an external file written in a made-up programming language. Here is an example of the language:

```
[while
   [x-is-larger-than 300]
   [seq
      [command1]
      [command2]
   ]
]
```

We were thinking about using different classes for each command or condition.

Our question is: how do we read and execute these commands in order?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this `[homework]`?  What have you tried?

Comment: Read the file line by line, then parse the read line via regular expressions, do the corresponding action.

Comment: @mert Regex? Ew. Looks like a simple lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to

1. Write a grammar for the invented language
2. Use a parser-generator to generate a parser for the language

and then

1. Use the parser to parse a given program.
2. Execute the program by traversing the AST directly,
   or,
   Compile the AST to a sequential program which is easy to interpret statement by statement.

Comment: Parsing should not be difficult. The problem is how to store the statements in order, execute while loops, check for conditions, ...

Comment: Once you have an AST, it's trivial to compile it into labeled statements and goto's which in turn are trivial to run by interpreting them.

Comment: Alright, we think we'll use an AST then, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Place all your commands in a stack / list

so you would have:

```
6: ]
5: ]
4: [command2]
3: [command1]
2: [seq
1: [x-is-larger-than 300]
0: [while
```

So if you read "While" .... save its stack position and run through it...

1. 0 -> start while
2. 1 -> x is larger than 300 ?
3. 2 -> if 2. sequence start else clear stack
4. 3 -> run commands untill ] reached
5. 4 -> start on saved stack position (0) -> start at 1.

Thats sth what I would do.
Getting the commands into code (parsing) will be yours! ;)